# WCF throw exception

Tags: wcf

```
 <s:Body>
<s:Fault>
  <s:Code>
    <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
    <s:Subcode>
      <s:Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:DeserializationFailed</s:Value>
    </s:Subcode>
  </s:Code>
  <s:Reason>
    <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:dataSet. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Data.DataSet. '��&lt;http://tempuri.org/ISplSynchronizationContracts/ApplyChangesD&#x1A;' contains invalid UTF8 bytes.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.</s:Text>
  </s:Reason>
  <s:Detail>
    <ExceptionDetail xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel">
      <HelpLink i:nil="true" />
      <InnerException>
        <HelpLink i:nil="true" />
        <InnerException>
          <HelpLink i:nil="true" />
          <InnerException>
            <HelpLink i:nil="true" />
            <InnerException i:nil="true" />
            <Message>Unable to translate bytes [82] at index 0 from specified code page to Unicode.</Message>
            <StackTrace>   at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Throw(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Byte[] bytes, Byte* pBytes, Char*&amp; chars)
```

I use custom binding in WCF and sometime getting the above error. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: What is your custum binding doing?

Answer (score 0):

The exception contains the text: `contains invalid UTF8 bytes`

It's hard to verify based on the limited context, but I would assume that somewhere along the line, you're serializing to UTF-16 or some other format, and the service is failing at that.

Ensure that all objects being serialized are explicitly serialized using UTF-8.

Comment: I use Microsoft Ado.Net sync services over WCF services. Data set object is internally transmitted by sync services.